# Creating multiple lines from one Array using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am trying to create multiple lines from a single array. What I want to do is have a single destination point and have all the other point make lines to this destinations point. I am using arrays to create polylines, however I am unsure how to create a loop which makes polylines using one point and then going through the array and creating a new line for each point in the array.

I am using python 3 in ArcGIS Pro.

Io illustrate:

Points Array : `<Array [<Point (1,2), <Point (3,4)>,<Point (5,6)>, <Point (7,8)>]>`

I want to make the lines using these points:

```
(1,2),(3,4) 
(1,2), (5,6)
(1,2), (7,8)
```

Comment: Please add an image to your question to visualise what you want?

Comment: Can ba done without coding. Add coordinates to many points. Run near tool with location between them and single point. Use xy to line, using many points table as input.

Comment: You want one line looking like an asterix?