# Creating multiple layers from string of coordinates in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I would like to know if it is possible to create multiple layers from stringified coordinates within one layer. I have a layer with one field containing a string of coordinates, which I would like to split up in several point layers. For example my attribute table looks like this:

| FID | String Coordinates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 55.27517,-142.08384; -71.56405,5.49818; 4.13471,-165.51177; 6.89592,-164.22896 |
| 2 | 45.58417,-50.15136; -40.11681,5.49818; -28.57185,128.38152;-48.65803,-78.15412 |
| 3 | 9.51578,-20.82284; 3.92250,78.47350; 3.72252,102.14385; -12.93206,130.76959 |
| 4 | 33.01124,-85.81893; -22.16111,86.19250; 14.78448,-165.51177; -37.18276,-22.60942 |

I want to create a separate point layer from every coordinates pair.

Is there a way to achieve this, preferably using ModelBuilder?

---

I found this, but I was not able to follow/realize the instructions in the comment: [Creating multiple lines from one Array using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/378302/176525)

Comment: This is best done as a python script as you need to manipulate lists, coordinate pairs, geometry and featureclasses. Model builder does not expose that fine grain manipulation you require.

Comment: but is it possible to add an external python script to model builder and run it as part of the process?

Comment: Yes you can put python in the calculate value tool. But so much of your required logic is likely to be driven by python I would abandon the idea of accomplishing this in model builder.